# Programmatically setting up colspan for a html td

Tags: php, netbeans

I am trying to setup the column span of a html cell using the code below;

```
<td colspan="<?php echo $col_nos; ?>"  style="text-align: center;">
```

Netbeans throws up an error - a long red highlight of that line of code with a message that says;

```
Bad value " " on attribute 'colspan' on element 'td'. Expected a digit but 
saw " " instead.
```

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

Update 1:

Full line of code...

```
<tr  style="background: white !important; "><td colspan="<?php echo $col_nos; ?>"  
style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $params['page']; ?></td></tr>
```

Rendered html output - retrieved from Ctrl+U of Output

```
<td colspan="8" style="text-align: center;">
```

Comment: I dont see any problem with that line of code.

Comment: have you checked $col_nos; contains a valid digit?

Comment: You need to post some more of portion your code to solve this.

Comment: Posting the html output and code

Comment: this is the html output ; <td colspan="8" style="text-align: center;">

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the code is saved in a `.html` file, thus Netbeans interprets it as HTML only.
There are two ways to tell Netbeans that within a HTML file PHP code is used:

- rename the file from `page.html` to `page.php`
- go to Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files and select for the file extension `html` the associated file type as `text/x-php5`

Now Netbeans is able to process blocks of PHP code in HTML files correctly.

[image: Netbeans options]

Comment: What version of Netbeans do you have? What associated file type has the file extension `php`?